# Use a separate thread to execute a list of commands in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17

I have a `DataClass` class which has some data that needs to be `generated` and `cleaned`.
I don't know at which time during the execution of the program I'll have new data, and I was trying to use multiple threads to allow for the main one to proceed while the data is being processed.

this is the `DataClass`:

```
class DataClass
{
public:
    unsigned int state{0};

    
    void Generate()
    {
        using namespace std::chrono_literals;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(3s);
        state = 1;
    }

    void Clean()
    {
        using namespace std::chrono_literals;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
        state = 2;
    }
};
```

I'm holding each DataClass object into two `std::deque`, one with the ones that needs to be generated and another with the ones that need to be cleaned.

```
std::deque<DataClass*> dataToGenerate;
std::deque<DataClass*> dataToClean;
```

I am using two function `CleanerFunction` and `GeneratorFunction` which will process the content of the two lists.

`GeneratorFunction`:

```
void GeneratorFunction()
{
    while (!dataToGenerate.empty())
    {
        auto* c = dataToGenerate.front();
        c->Generate();
        dataToGenerate.pop_front();
        dataToClean.push_back(c);
        std::cout << "Generated one Data Piece." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

(The cleaner one is similar).

And in the main function I start two threads for the two functions.
But the threads stop instantly as the two lists are empty and so I would need to create a new one each time. I've looked into condition_variables but I cannot get them to work properly as all the examples I found online were different from this scenario.
As far as I understood if I use a while(!dataToGenerate.empty()) I will execute that line always filling a thread without any actual reason, so I wanted to not use this method.

Is there a way that I could pause each thread until the lists are not empty anymore and then start the thread?

Comment: Let the thread run forever (or until you send it a shut-down signal), and if the queue is empty, sleep for a short duration. Or you can let the thread sleep until a condition_variable is trigger, and only then let it go back to work until the queue is empt again and then again sleep until a condition variable is triggered. Also, you need to add some synchronization for the threads, protect the queues with mutexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [XY ratio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) of this question seems rather high. I'd read up on task queuing and locking and rephrase your solution in terms of that.

In particular, you would find this close to a producer/consumer pattern.

### Queue

Let's start with a minimal generic locking queue:

```
template <typename T>
struct Queue {
    Queue(size_t max = 50) : _max(max) {}

    size_t enqueue(T v) {
        std::unique_lock lk(_mx);
        _cond.wait(lk, [this] { return (_max == 0) || (_storage.size() < _max); });

        _storage.push_back(std::move(v));
        _cond.notify_one();
        return _storage.size(); // NOTE: very racy load indicator
    }

    template <typename Duration>
    std::optional<T> dequeue(Duration d) {
        std::unique_lock lk(_mx);

        if (_cond.wait_for(lk, d, [this] { return !_storage.empty(); })) {
            auto top = std::move(_storage.front());

            _storage.pop_front();
            _cond.notify_one();

            return top;
        }

        return std::nullopt;
    }

  private:
    size_t _max;
    mutable std::mutex _mx;
    mutable std::condition_variable _cond;
    std::deque<T> _storage;
};
```

This never blocks on dequeue (so you can detect and handle queue-empty). It will in principle not block on enqueue unless a certain limit has been reached. Make the limit 0 to have an unbounded queue.

Now you can have any number of queues with any number of producers/consumers you wish. E.g.:

### Program Logic

```
struct DataClass {
    int id;
    unsigned int state{ 0 };

    DataClass(int id) : id(id) {}

    void Generate() { sleep_for(3s); state = 1; }
    void Clean()    { sleep_for(1s); state = 2; }
};
```

Now let's make a program with 4 generator threads and 2 cleaner threads, monitoring 2 queus (genTasks and cleanTasks).

```
struct Program {
    Program() {
        auto worker_id = 1;
        _workers.emplace_back([this, id=worker_id++] { generate_worker(id); });
        _workers.emplace_back([this, id=worker_id++] { generate_worker(id); });
        _workers.emplace_back([this, id=worker_id++] { generate_worker(id); });
        _workers.emplace_back([this, id=worker_id++] { generate_worker(id); });
        _workers.emplace_back([this, id=worker_id++] { clean_worker(id); });
        _workers.emplace_back([this, id=worker_id++] { clean_worker(id); });
    }

    size_t createWork(DataClass task) {
        return genTasks.enqueue(std::move(task));
    }

    ~Program() {
        _shutdown = true;
        for (auto& th: _workers) 
            if (th.joinable()) th.join();
    }

  private:
    Queue<DataClass> genTasks, cleanTasks;
    std::atomic_bool _shutdown { false };
    std::list<std::thread> _workers;

    void generate_worker(int worker_id) {
        while (!_shutdown) {
            while (auto task = genTasks.dequeue(1s)) {
                std::cout << "Worker #" << worker_id << " Generate: " << task->id << std::endl;
                task->Generate();
                cleanTasks.enqueue(std::move(*task));
            }
        }
        std::cout << "Worker #" << worker_id << " Exit generate_worker" << std::endl;
    }

    void clean_worker(int worker_id) {
        while (!_shutdown) {
            while (auto task = cleanTasks.dequeue(1s)) {
                std::cout << "Worker #" << worker_id << " Clean: " << task->id << std::endl;
                task->Clean();
                std::cout << "Worker #" << worker_id << " Done: " << task->id << std::endl;
            }
        }
        std::cout << "Worker #" << worker_id << " Exit clean_worker" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

I added a `_shutdown` flag for good measure, though it's not very forceful (it waits until the workers are idle for at least one second (`dequeue(1s)`). If you want more intrusive shutdown, sprinkle some `if (_shutdown) break;` statements through the worker loops.

### Full Demo

Let's drive it with some work:

```
int main() {
    Program p; 

    for (auto i : {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}) {
        sleep_for((rand()%100) * 1ms);
        p.createWork(i);
    }

    sleep_for(2.5s);
    std::cout << "Load at createWork(42) is ~" << p.createWork(42) << std::endl;
    sleep_for(2.5s);
    std::cout << "Load at createWork(43) is ~" << p.createWork(43) << std::endl;

    sleep_for(4s);
    std::cout << "Initiating shutdown\n";
    // Program destructor performs shutdown
}
```

Prints

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d762af78c1a82be7)**

```
Worker #2 Generate: 1
Worker #1 Generate: 2
Worker #3 Generate: 3
Worker #4 Generate: 4
Worker #2 Generate: 5
Worker #5 Clean: 1
Load at createWork(42) is ~6
Worker #1 Generate: 6
Worker #6 Clean: 2
Worker #3 Generate: 7
Worker #4 Generate: 8
Worker #5 Done: 1
Worker #5 Clean: 3
Worker #6 Done: 2
Worker #6 Clean: 4
Worker #5 Done: 3
Worker #6 Done: 4
Load at createWork(43) is ~4
Worker #2 Generate: 9
Worker #5 Clean: 5
Worker #1 Generate: 10
Worker #6 Clean: 6
Worker #3 Generate: 42
Worker #4 Generate: 43
Worker #5 Done: 5
Worker #5 Clean: 7
Worker #6 Done: 6
Worker #6 Clean: 8
Worker #5 Done: 7
Worker #6 Done: 8
Worker #5 Clean: 9
Worker #6 Clean: 10
Initiating shutdown
Worker #2 Exit generate_worker
Worker #5 Done: 9
Worker #5 Clean: 42
Worker #1 Exit generate_worker
Worker #6 Done: 10
Worker #6 Clean: 43
Worker #3 Exit generate_worker
Worker #4 Exit generate_worker
Worker #5 Done: 42
Worker #6 Done: 43
Worker #5 Exit clean_worker
Worker #6 Exit clean_worker
Unfinished generate/clean tasks: 0/0
```

### Full Listing

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d762af78c1a82be7)**

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <deque>
#include <optional>

template <typename T>
struct Queue {
    Queue(size_t max = 50) : _max(max) {}

    size_t enqueue(T v) {
        std::unique_lock lk(_mx);
        _cond.wait(lk, [this] { return (_max == 0) || (_storage.size() < _max); });

        _storage.push_back(std::move(v));
        _cond.notify_one();
        return _storage.size(); // NOTE: very racy load indicator
    }

    template <typename Duration>
    std::optional<T> dequeue(Duration d) {
        std::unique_lock lk(_mx);

        if (_cond.wait_for(lk, d, [this] { return !_storage.empty(); })) {
            auto top = std::move(_storage.front());

            _storage.pop_front();
            _cond.notify_one();

            return top;
        }

        return std::nullopt;
    }

    size_t size() const { // racy in multi-thread situations
        std::unique_lock lk(_mx);
        return _storage.size();
    }

  private:
    size_t _max;
    mutable std::mutex _mx;
    mutable std::condition_variable _cond;
    std::deque<T> _storage;
};

#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <atomic>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
static inline auto sleep_for = [](auto d) { std::this_thread::sleep_for(d); };

struct DataClass {
    int id;
    unsigned int state{ 0 };

    DataClass(int id) : id(id) {}
    //DataClass(DataClass&&) = default;
    //DataClass& operator=(DataClass&&) = default;
    //DataClass(DataClass const&) = delete;

    void Generate() { sleep_for(3s); state = 1; }
    void Clean()    { sleep_for(1s); state = 2; }
};

struct Program {
    Program() {
        auto worker_id = 1;
        _workers.emplace_back([this, id=worker_id++] { generate_worker(id); });
        _workers.emplace_back([this, id=worker_id++] { generate_worker(id); });
        _workers.emplace_back([this, id=worker_id++] { generate_worker(id); });
        _workers.emplace_back([this, id=worker_id++] { generate_worker(id); });
        _workers.emplace_back([this, id=worker_id++] { clean_worker(id); });
        _workers.emplace_back([this, id=worker_id++] { clean_worker(id); });
    }

    size_t createWork(DataClass task) {
        return genTasks.enqueue(std::move(task));
    }

    ~Program() {
        _shutdown = true;
        for (auto& th: _workers) 
            if (th.joinable()) th.join();
        std::cout << "Unfinished generate/clean tasks: " << genTasks.size() << "/" << cleanTasks.size() << "\n";
    }

  private:
    Queue<DataClass> genTasks, cleanTasks;
    std::atomic_bool _shutdown { false };
    std::list<std::thread> _workers;

    void generate_worker(int worker_id) {
        while (!_shutdown) {
            while (auto task = genTasks.dequeue(1s)) {
                std::cout << "Worker #" << worker_id << " Generate: " << task->id << std::endl;
                task->Generate();
                cleanTasks.enqueue(std::move(*task));
            }
        }
        std::cout << "Worker #" << worker_id << " Exit generate_worker" << std::endl;
    }

    void clean_worker(int worker_id) {
        while (!_shutdown) {
            while (auto task = cleanTasks.dequeue(1s)) {
                std::cout << "Worker #" << worker_id << " Clean: " << task->id << std::endl;
                task->Clean();
                std::cout << "Worker #" << worker_id << " Done: " << task->id << std::endl;
            }
        }
        std::cout << "Worker #" << worker_id << " Exit clean_worker" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Program p; 

    for (auto i : {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}) {
        sleep_for((rand()%100) * 1ms);
        p.createWork(i);
    }

    sleep_for(2.5s);
    std::cout << "Load at createWork(42) is ~" << p.createWork(42) << std::endl;
    sleep_for(2.5s);
    std::cout << "Load at createWork(43) is ~" << p.createWork(43) << std::endl;

    sleep_for(4s);
    std::cout << "Initiating shutdown\n";
    // Program destructor performs shutdown
}
```

Comment: Just to show there's many ways to skin a cat: [the same in less than 45% of the code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a194bf593caab9b7) using Boost Asio for the task queuing.

Comment: Ah just remembered I wasnted to emphasize that shared_ptr is rarely required, so that last one with `unique_ptr` instead: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dcf78c82a78091e6